# Migrate a new SVN Repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to migrate certain projects from one SVN to another. Both repositories have other projects with multiple revisions. 
I am trying to move project from one repository to another along with its commit history. The revision numbers are not important and ideally, i would like to only copy the past year of commit history as we don't need more than that and i believe it would be too time consuming to copy the entire history.

I have looked at svnsync but i believe it does not fit my purpose as the new repository is not starting at 0

Answer (score 1):

To dump a repository into a particular format, you use:

```
$ svnadmin dump $REPO_DIR > dumpfile
```

You can use `svndumpfilter` to specify what you want to dump:

```
$ svnadmin dump $REPO_DIR | svndumpfilter include $REPOPREFIX > dumpfile
```

This way, you're only dumping out the projects you want.

When you get your dump-file, you can use `svnadmin load` to load it:

```
$ svnadmin load $REPO_PATH < dumpfile
```

The problem is that you cannot load your old repositories to already existing directories. In that case, you may have to specify `--parent-dir`:

```
$ svnadmin load --parent-dir /second_repo < dumpfile
```

After you've finished with the load, you can move that directory to another location.

See the on-line Subversion manual on [Migrating Repository Data Elsewhere](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of revisions is small (less than say 20) then I'd do it manually. Update-to-revision in old, copy files to new and commit. Repeat 50 times.

You could make a script that would have the list of revisions to which it would update the old working copy, and in a loop do the update/copy/commit process.

In the TortoiseSVN installation folder there are command line apps `svn` and `svnlook` that would help you in making the script mentioned above.